# Can Haskell's garbage collector prematurely collect "inner" objects?

Tags: haskell

```hs
data Car = Car { carName :: String, carFunctionality :: ByteString }

main :: IO ()
main = do
    complexFunctionality <- undefined -- create complex functionality
    let myCar = Car {
                 carName = "myCar",
                 carFunctionality = complexFunctionality }

    -- A) Call functions that use myCar, but only use carName.
    --    They don't use the carFunctionality.

    -- B) From here on, myCar is never again used.
```

Questions:

1. Once B) is reached, will the garbage collector (the next time it's triggered) collect `myCar`? I can answer this myself. The answer is clearly yes because this is the whole point of GC.
2. More important question. During the function calls in A), is there any risk of `complexFunctionality` getting collected just because it is nowhere being used? In other words, I'm wondering if it's possible for an object (`complexFunctionality`) getting collected before the surrounding object `myCar` gets collected.
3. Can your answer in 2. be relied on, i.e., is it future-proof (well documented behavior of Haskell and not just an accidental feature of the current GHC)?

Comment: A garbage collector simulates a computer with infinite memory. If your program can detect a garbage collector (even if by crashing/behaving erroneously), then the garbage collector has a bug, by definition.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Your first statement is fine. The second seems an overstatement to me. I can get a pointer to some object, disguise that pointer in a way the GC can't recognize (e.g. convert it to an int), then convert it back and try to reference the object. In this way, I can detect whether the GC has collected my object and reused its memory for something else. And yet, the bug is in my program, not in the GC.

Comment: @amalloy In the simulated infinite-memory machine the size of the pointer is also infinite. When you convert it to an int, only a finite amount of bits is preserved. Of course collisions are possible, they don't mean GC is present.

Comment: That seems a bizarrely specific constraint to assume. Why doesn't my infinite-memory machine with infinite-size pointers have infinite-size ints? Why can't I hide my pointer in some other way?

Comment: Because that's what the garbage collector *does*. Simulates an infinite-memory machine where you don't get to see the true addresses (you see only mangled/shortened/whatever addresses). Or at least that's what an ideal model of GC does. Specific implementations may be different. If you think it's a bizarre thing to simulate, well go ahead and simulate something other thing. But your simulator probably would not be an ideal GC.

Comment: If the field is unused then it won't be a bytestring in memory but a thunk.

Comment: The answer to 1) is more like `myCar` is *eligible* to be garbage-collected. *When* it's collected is an implementation detail of your garbage collector. (I can imagine a garbage collector that could be triggered but do nothing if memory usage hasn't reached a critical threshold yet, or free only enough objects to reach some other lower usage threshold; no sense reclaiming memory that won't be needed later.)

Answer (score 7):

You talk about question 2 in terms of a "risk". This is a curious choice of phrasing: how would such GC behavior affect you negatively? In practice, GHC will probably not collect your sub-object. In principle, a sufficiently smart GC might do so if it has enough insight into how your program behaves, e.g. through inlining. The point of garbage collection is that it only occurs for objects you won't use again. If you're not using them again, why is it a "risk" that they might be collected? Rather most people would see it as a benefit! This obsolete object can be collected early, freeing up memory for objects which are presently more important. So again, I suggest thinking more about why you consider this a risk: if you consider it dangerous, probably either your assumptions or your program are broken.

Comment: The only potential reason is finalization. Trying to impose any kind of ordering or timing on finalization is a pretty bad idea, but maybe the OP wants a finalizer on the inner value to force finalization of the outer one, and hopes that the outer one is guaranteed to be dead? I don't think that's going to work out very well.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer to (2) is "no".  GHC's garbage collector is designed so that if a multi-field value is marked as "used", all of its fields (its "inner objects") are also marked as "used".  As @amalloy has pointed out, this is not necessarily a good thing.  It would probably be *better* if an unused object could be garbage collected even if it was a field of some used object.  However, designing a garbage collector to do this is difficult and mostly pointless (as I'll explain in a minute), which also helps answer (3):  yes, it's pretty much guaranteed that the GHC garbage collector will never be redesigned to collect "inner objects" from in-use "outer objects".

The reason designing a garbage collector to collect unused fields of used objects is pointless is that this is something that can better be accomplished during compilation, by applying appropriate optimizations.  Consider the following program:

```
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS

data Car = Car { carName :: String, carFunctionality :: ByteString }

main :: IO ()
main = do
  complexFunctionality <- BS.readFile "/etc/passwd"
  let myCar = Car {
        carName = "myCar",
        carFunctionality = complexFunctionality }
  print $ carName myCar
  print "done with myCar"
```

If you compile this with optimizations and dump the optimized code, using:

```
ghc -O2 Example1.hs -fforce-recomp -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all -dsuppress-uniques
```

the resulting optimized code (which is admittedly hard to read) is equivalent to:

```
main = do
    BS.readFile "/etc/passwd"
    print "myCar"
    print "done with myCar"
```

(In fact, if you compile this version instead, the resulting optimized code is exactly the same as the optimized code for the original `main`.)

GHC does not optimize away the `readFile` itself, because it's an I/O operation, and GHC does not optimize away I/O operations, even if they "obviously" have no effect.  But, the result of the `readFile` is ignored, which means that -- effectively -- the `carProperties` `ByteString` can be garbage collected immediately after the `readFile` statement.  For that matter, the `Car` object is optimized away entirely, so it is never created much less garbage collected.

So, the bottom line is that compile-time optimizations can usually realize most of the benefits of "inner object garbage collection" by eliminating the dependency of an "outer object" on an "inner object" in the first place, which means that the garbage collector itself doesn't need any special functionality to identify and collect "inner objects", as they'll naturally be collected as unused objects in the optimized code.

Comment: If you use `-dsuppress-all`, I recommend adding `-dno-suppress-type-signatures`, but I usually just use `-dsuppress-type-applications` and `-dsuppress-coercions` instead. Sometimes also `-dsuppress-module-prefixes`. I really dislike `-dsuppress-uniques`—while it makes the code look a lot less scary, it also risks extremely confusing name confusion. I really wish there were a `-dminimize-uniques` that would use just enough of them, but that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

There are some cases where an optimization in GHC's GC algorithm can cause it to collect unused fields in a data type.  [This section of the heap object documentation](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/rts/storage/heap-objects#selector-thunks) describes a type of heap object, the selector thunk, which is created from certain code specifically to enable this optimization.

Selector thunks are generated for any function which of the form `\x -> case x of Pat n1 n2 n3 ... -> nk`. IE, a function that matches a single constructor and returns exactly one field from it. When the garbage collector encounters a selector thunk applied to a value, it will look ahead. If the value is already evaluated and matches the expected constructor, it will rewrite the thunk to be a direct reference to that field, removing a reference to the containing data value. If the containing value is no longer reachable from the GC roots, it value is forgotten and will be collected by the garbage collector along with anything it contained which is no longer reachable.

This process can result in situations where unused record fields get collected while you still might think of the current state as having the whole record closed over by an unevaluated expression. But this is both a rare situation and you need a somewhat sophisticated mental model for how laziness works to even recognize when laziness says it might be keeping more in memory than necessary.